# pyfpdf: FPDF error: Undefined font: calibri B

Tags: python, fpdf, pyfpdf

I added the font calibri.fft,calibrii.fft, and calibrib.fft but error still exist.

`pdf.add_font('Calibri','','Calibri.ttf',uni=True)`

`pdf.add_font('Calibri I','','Calibrii.ttf',uni=True)`

`pdf.add_font('Calibri B','','Calibrib.ttf',uni=True)`

Underline works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like i messed up my syntax, fixed it using this syntax:

`pdf.add_font('Calibri','I','Calibrii.ttf',uni=True)`

`pdf.add_font('Calibri','B','Calibrib.ttf',uni=True)`